# Create new dataframe through merging of rows with similar (non-numeric) column values

Tags: r, merge, row

I am quite new to R and I am struggling with the following:

I have a dataset that looks as follows. We have columns tnummer1 till tnummer8 (only showed tnummer1 till tnummer3 in example). I want to merge rows with similar value for endoscopieuri, so we will have 1 row for each endoscopieuri.

| endoscopieuri | tnummer1 | tnummer2 | tnummer3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5e0998958f7a8ff4ebf5d46ba34b2ecb12543d4 | 22c51a38ffe764594e058eca8b43549744 | N/A | N/A |
| 5e0998958f7a8ff4ebf5d46ba34b2ecb12543d4 | N/A | 06b77b6ad508c6a70be9d388fae9 | N/A |
| 7beb994b345cd5823982a7aff7500731103b109d8bb769658 | 009da068f54f7fea90577809257d5f2e163dc78ee2016ad7b0 | N/A | N/A |
| 31565f0ba884ad7332cef7e31b70db941d133c6c263c4ef26 | 00addb8d09faa329c45990186a97577a7cc800c5421fc4e229 | N/A | N/A |
| a4b1bd7cd9ba916f9e8a8de653274aed6a69e299468d9a82 | 00b24f7e4192d8dc42a2d375443f547889af480e788ece32ed | N/A | N/A |
| e0b7a4cce9c3baffea364e2545c4711f38621ac6643ba6 | 00cc18db5123636836b72973af54e20910f35b9c1fb51628 | N/A | N/A |
| e0b7a4cce9c3baffea364e2545c4711f38621ac6643ba6 | N/A | 00d32502ab51a4f9c91a23af50d1a69b9539ee458735fbb | N/A |
| e0b7a4cce9c3baffea364e2545c4711f38621ac6643ba6 | N/A | N/A | 00d49c54fe6bfcdba4fbce83d7ea0337373df208f7e12ce34b |

I want the dataset to look at follows:

| endoscopieuri | tnummer1 | tnummer2 | tnummer3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5e0998958f7a8ff4ebf5d46ba34b2ecb12543d4 | 22c51a38ffe764594e058eca8b43549744 | 06b77b6ad508c6a70be9d388fae9 | N/A |
| 7beb994b345cd5823982a7aff7500731103b109d8bb769658 | 009da068f54f7fea90577809257d5f2e163dc78ee2016ad7b0 | N/A | N/A |
| 31565f0ba884ad7332cef7e31b70db941d133c6c263c4ef26 | 00addb8d09faa329c45990186a97577a7cc800c5421fc4e229 | N/A | N/A |
| a4b1bd7cd9ba916f9e8a8de653274aed6a69e299468d9a82 | 00b24f7e4192d8dc42a2d375443f547889af480e788ece32ed | N/A | N/A |
| e0b7a4cce9c3baffea364e2545c4711f38621ac6643ba6 | 00cc18db5123636836b72973af54e20910f35b9c1fb51628 | 00d32502ab51a4f9c91a23af50d1a69b9539ee458735fbb | 00d49c54fe6bfcdba4fbce83d7ea0337373df208f7e12ce34b |

I tried several strategies using  `summarise` and `aggregate` functions of `dplyr`, but this did not provide me with a solution, while this are non-numeric variables. I think a solution should be quite simple, but I have not been able to find any so far.

Thank you!